# How to make a repeatable iterator with python

Tags: python, iterator

Is there any way to make an iterator can use repeatly?

I am trying to train something **not pictures** with CNN model. To save RAM, I use `fit_generate()` to fit data. As far as I know, only iterator object can use in `fit_generate()`. But I cannot use the function `ImageDataGernerater()` from Keras. The only way is to make an iterator myself. I tried `iter()`, and it is not a repeatable iterator definitely.

Answer (score 0):

You can make repeatable iterators, yes. How exactly would they work here?

One thing I could imagine would be making a generator repeatable, by just making the `__iter__` call re-initialize the generator:

```
from functools import wraps

def repeatable(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return RepeatableGenerator(fn, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


class RepeatableGenerator:
    def __init__(self, gen, *args, **kwargs):
        self.gen = gen
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.it = None

    def __iter__(self):
        self.it = self.gen(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        return next(self.it)
```

You could then either decorate your own generators with it:

```
>>> @repeatable
>>> def generator():
...     yield 1
...     yield 2
>>> g = generator()
>>> list(g)
[1, 2]
>>> list(g)
[1, 2]
```

Or you could apply this to some existing generator:

```
from foo_lib import bar_generator

bar_generator = repeatable(bar_generator)
```